# Put request info into response of Haskell webserver

Tags: haskell

I completely new to Haskell so probably its a basic question.

I have following webserver code that prints out "Hello World!" when you navigate to `http://localhost:8080` in your browser.

What I trying to achieve is instead of showing "Hello World!" I want to see just the request info data such as headers, path, host, body, etc.

Is it possible?

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.ByteString.Char8 ()
import Network hiding ( accept )
import Network.Socket ( accept )
import Network.Socket.ByteString ( sendAll )
import Control.Monad ( forever )
import Control.Exception ( bracket, finally )
import Control.Concurrent ( forkIO )

main :: IO ()
main = bracket (listenOn $ PortNumber 8080) sClose loop where
  loop s = forever $ forkIO . request . fst =<< accept s
  request c = sendAll c response `finally` sClose c
  response = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\nContent-Length: 13\n\nHello World!\n"
```

Or alternatively same logic with Warp package:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Network.Wai
import Network.Wai.Handler.Warp
import Network.HTTP.Types (status200)
import Blaze.ByteString.Builder (copyByteString)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BU
import Data.Monoid

main = do
    let port = 8080
    putStrLn $ "Listening on port " ++ show port
    run port app

app req respond = respond $
    case pathInfo req of
        x -> index x

index x = responseBuilder status200 [("Content-Type", "text/plain")] $ mconcat $ map copyByteString
    [ "Hello World!\n" ]
```

I just need to put request information instead "Hello World!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [recv](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-3.1.1.1/docs/Network-Socket-ByteString.html#v:recv) function to get the request information. First, add it to your imports

```hs
import Network.Socket.ByteString ( sendAll, recv )
```

Next, use it in `main`:

```hs
main :: IO ()
main = bracket (listenOn $ PortNumber 8080) sClose loop where
  loop s = forever $ forkIO . request . fst =<< accept s
  request c = do info <- recv c 1024               -- Get the request information
                 print info                        -- Print info to console
                 sendAll c info `finally` sClose c -- Send info as response
```

Comment: How do I print it? Or sending with response?

Comment: Right now it's sending the request text as the response. To print it, just add  `print info` in between the two lines in the do-notation. I'll edit my answer with an example.